# TextEditingController makes widget lose its previous state

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

When I use `TextEditingController` in `CupertinoTextField`, and change to another widget(page) and return, the previous state in that page is lost.

When I uncomment `//controller: textController,` everything works fine.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'test',
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [new Search(), new Setting(),
              ],
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: Container(
              height: 60,
              child: new TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.search)),
                  Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.settings)),
                ],
                labelColor: Colors.blue,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              ),
            )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Setting extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.check),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
              new Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(title: Text('3'),),
              )));
        });
  }

}

class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => new SearchState();
}

class SearchState extends State<Search> {

  String currentWord = '';
  final TextEditingController textController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new CupertinoTextField(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  cursorColor: Colors.white,
                  //controller: textController,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  clearButtonMode: OverlayVisibilityMode.editing,
                  onChanged: (text) {
                    setState(() {
                      currentWord = text;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 5,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return Text(currentWord);
            })
    );
  }

}
```

The expected result(without controller set):get back and the state keeps the same.

[image: expected]

Actual results(with controller set): get back and the state lost

[image: actual]

Comment: @JeromeEscalante I have tried to remove `textController.dispose();`, and it's still not working.

Comment: It's weird for me that it even works, since I thought bottomnav recreates a new navigation on entering a tabbar.

Comment: @Syph Sorry, I don't quite understand, do you have a better implementation?

Comment: No, I thought the default behaviour was like your second example. Your state lies within your navigator, however in each tab lies a separate navigator. Your navigator will remember the stack of your views, but when you try to go to a different tab, it disposes your current tab.

Comment: @Syph wired thing is that in my first example, `Search` is not disposed, while in second example, `Search` is disposed in Widget `3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation for the observed behavior is the following:

`CupertinoTextField` uses an internal `TextEditingController` for which the framework automatically sets an `AutomaticKeepAlive`. This keepAlive is responsible for keeping the state.

If you use your own controller, you are in charge of attaching the `AutomaticKeepAlive` because the framework doesn't do it for you.

The following snippet adds the keepAlive to your code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'test',
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                new Search(),
                new Setting(),
              ],
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: Container(
              height: 60,
              child: new TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.search)),
                  Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.settings)),
                ],
                labelColor: Colors.blue,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Setting extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.check),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              CupertinoPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => new Scaffold(
                        appBar: AppBar(
                          title: Text('3'),
                        ),
                      )));
        });
  }
}

class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => new SearchState();
}

class SearchState extends State<Search> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  String currentWord = '';
  final TextEditingController textController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textController?.addListener(updateKeepAlive);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textController?.removeListener(updateKeepAlive);
    textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context); // See AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin.
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new CupertinoTextField(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  cursorColor: Colors.white,
                  controller: textController,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  clearButtonMode: OverlayVisibilityMode.editing,
                  onChanged: (text) {
                    setState(() {
                      currentWord = text;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 5,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return Text(currentWord);
            }));
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => textController?.text?.isNotEmpty == true;
}
```

Comment: In MaterialApp its happening the opposite. When i pop the screen out and visit again the TextField has the previous text. How can I remove that ?

Comment: How are you creating the page? Some code would help. Maybe in another question.